# Populate the values of select boxes dynamically from another select box

Tags: javascript, php

I have two select options of `Countries` and `States`. The option values are populating from database using `php` functions. I would like to populate the `States` depending on the selection of `Countries`. For example, if I select US from `Countries` then `States` select option will populate me all the `States` belongs to the US Country.

Here is my code -

```
<select id="countryName" name="countryName" onChange="getCountryCode()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php $countries = $location->getCountries();
         foreach ($countries as $country) {
             echo '<option value="' . $country->id . '">' . $country->name . '</option>';
         }
    ?>                                        
</select>
```

I can get the selected country value using `javascript` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getCountryCode(){
         var countryCode = document.getElementById('countryName').value;
     }
</script>
```

After all these, I am trying to get the `States` of selected `Country` using the php function `getStates($countryCode)`. But I don't know how to pass the `javascript` variable to `php` function.

```
<select name="stateName">
     <option value=""></option>
     <?php $states = $location->getStates($countryCode);
          foreach ($states as $state) {
              echo '<option value="' . $state->id . '">' . $state->name . '</option>';
          }
     ?>
</select>
```

Does anyone have any idea how do I pass the javascript variable to php or if have better idea than this, please do share.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use Ajax for that, binding it's call to an `.on('change')` event.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, do you mind to share it with some example. Sorry, but I am not good in javascript or Ajax.

Comment: I'd suggest having a read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming It also has a reference to another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript/23741119 that together should get you to the finish line.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you mix JavaScript code (client side) with PHP code (server side). That's not possible that way. After you send your content to the browser, php has to wait, till the user takes some action which calls the server again. In your case, there are two possible solutions.

1. Use AJAX to get the content of the state select box from the server. One way could be a simple php script, which just prints the states:

PHP Script

```
$states = $location->getStates($_GET['state']);
foreach ($states as $state) {
    echo '<option value="' . $state->id . '">' . $state->name . '</option>';
}
```

Javascript (using jQuery)

```
$('#countryName').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'states.php',
        data: { state: $(this).val() },
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data) {
            $('select[name="stateName"]').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

2. Another solution without ajax would be to print always all states and show/hide them in relation to the value of your country select box

PHP script

```
$states = $location->getAllStates();
foreach ($states as $state) {
    echo '<option data-country="{$state->country}" value="{$state->id}">{$state->name}</option>';
}
```

JavaScript (using jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    var $statesSelect = $('select[name="stateName"]');
    var $states = $('option', $statesSelect);
    // first remove all elements from dom
    $states.detach();
    // and then listen to change event and show/hide them
    $('#countryName').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $('option', $statesSelect).detach();
        $states.each(function() {
            $(this).is('[data-country="' + val + '"').appendTo($statesSelect);
        });
    });
});
```